# Обмен данными между страницами ASP. NET

Tags: asp.net

**Здравствуйте, товарищи!**

Со страницы 1 передаю данные:

```
string user = tb_Login.Text;
string pass = tb_Pass.Text;
string email = tb_Email.Text;
Response.Redirect("RegComplete.aspx?login=user&pass=pass&email=email");
```

На странице 2 получаю данные:

```
string username = Request.QueryString["login"];
string password = Request.QueryString["pass"];
string email = Request.QueryString["email"];
```

Результат: в строковые переменыне передаются НЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ, а ИМЕНА параметров (user, pass, email) в виде строки. Т.е. username = "user", password = "pass" и т.д.

**Как тут передать значения переменных? Подскажите, пожалуйста!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Товарищи!
Моя ошибка заключалась в том, что я передал параметр в виде строки с именем этого параметра!

Вот правильный вариант:

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("RegComplete.aspx?login={0}&pass={1}&email={2}", user, pass, email));
```

Надеюсь, это поможет кому-то :)